# I can not open Eclipse

Tags: java, logfiles

I'm trying to open Eclipse with a workspace that I normally use, but I got an error. Here is a part from the log (Any help is really appreciated):

```
      !SESSION 2014-01-22 10:01:39.699 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

This is a continuation of log file D:\PhD_SVN\Code\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-01-22 15:17:42.504

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-01-22 15:17:42.507
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.mouseMove(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.EventManager$8.invoke(EventManager.java:325)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.getFigureCanvas(Figure.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.Figure.getFigureCanvas(Figure.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.wb.draw2d.FigureUtils.translateFigureToCanvas(FigureUtils.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.controls.palette.PaletteComposite.getTargetFigure(PaletteComposite.java:1167)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.controls.palette.PaletteComposite.access$6(PaletteComposite.java:1164)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.controls.palette.PaletteComposite$EntryFigure.move_showFeedback(PaletteComposite.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.controls.palette.PaletteComposite$EntryFigure.access$12(PaletteComposite.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.controls.palette.PaletteComposite$EntryFigure$2.mouseMove(PaletteComposite.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.EventManager$4.invokeListener(EventManager.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.EventManager.sendEvent(EventManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.EventManager.handleMouseEvent(EventManager.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.EventManager.mouseMove(EventManager.java:184)
    ... 31 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-01-22 15:17:42.511
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
```

For more information, my Eclipse has only one plugin which is a GUI plug-in to create GUI with simple drag and drop mechanism.. Furthermore, all my code inside the workspace is OSGI bundles

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Error On Startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418709/eclipse-error-on-startup)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459661/eclipse-no-longer-starts?rq=1

Comment: Go to eclipse folder path in command prompt(shell) Run command eclipse -clean

Or

Delete old workbench(First copy all project present inside it). Start Eclipse.

Comment: how I can do that in windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you even need to install a plugin to get a drag and drop mechanism in Eclipse, but to quote IT Crowd:

> Have you tried turning it off and on again? (Delete->Re-install)

Comment: I have installed a new version of eclips but it doesn't work on the workspace also.

Comment: Have you also removed the old version of Eclipse?

Comment: I have removed the folder containing the old eclips, is that sufficient?

Comment: this does not answer the question. it should possibly be a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to backup your eclipse and adt folders when they're working nicely.

With this in mind, reinstall eclipse and back it up when it's running nicely.

Don't forget to give it as much memory as you can spare, especially if you're emulating an android device.

Answer (score 0):

According to the FAQ at the eclipse wiki.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F

> There is no mechanism within Eclipse to permanently and physically
>   uninstall a feature and its plug-ins. The process to physically and
>   permanently remove an undesirable feature and its plug-ins is a manual
>   process that should be done when Eclipse is not running. In order to
>   do, you will have to manually remove the files there associated with
>   the feature from the eclipse/features directory and its plug-ins from
>   the eclipse/plugins directory. Be very cautious as to which files you
>   delete, and always have a backup of your Eclipse directory. If you
>   remove the wrong files from these directories, you may have quite some
>   trouble restoring your Eclipse to a stable state. Therefore, unless
>   your hard disk storage capacity is extraordinarily limited, it is
>   recommended that you simply leave the physical files in place.

If it does not work, you can always download eclipse again and reinstall all other plugins you got. If you don't remember with one you got you can check directory eclipse/plugins.

In the future you should have a backup of eclipse every time you deiced to install a new plugin that way you can just roll back if anything goes wrong.